# Convert list of dictionary to nested list of dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries which I would like to combine into a single list.

```
a = [{"a1":1},{"a2":2}]
b = [{"b1":3},{"b2":4}]
```

How can I combine the above code into the following?:

```
c = [ {"a1":1,"b1":3}, {"a2":2,"b2":4} ]
```

Comment: Where is `a2` and `b2` in the list `a` and `b`?

Comment: soryy,its not a2 and b2 ,its a1 and b1 only.My mistake.@cph_so

Comment: So, the combining should be done sequentially? I mean, 1st element of `a` should be combined with 1st element of `b`. 2nd element of `a` with 2nd element of `b` and so on? That way, both the lists should be of the same length, right?

Comment: Yes, the same way, first element with first element and so on.Length of both lists are same.

Comment: I have posted the answer. If that is what was desired, could you accept it as an answer by pressing the tick button on the left hand side of the answer?

Comment: But a1 and b1  should be in single dictionary.Like a2 and b2.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP has said in his comments that the lists should be joined sequentially and the length of both the lists is equal.

```
a = [{"a1":1},{"a2":2}]
b = [{"b1":3},{"b2":4}]

out_list = a
for i in range(len(out_list)):
    out_list[i].update(b[i])

print(out_list)
[{'a1': 1, 'b1': 3}, {'a2': 2, 'b2': 4}]
```

Comment: Pleasure Shivaraj!